# Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > Failed to find Build Tools revision 30.0.3

Tags: flutter, build-tools

Even a new project created with flutter wouldn't run and still give this error.

Answer (score 0):

I searched a lot on the internet and tried this and it worked. If this answer is repetitive with any other solutions in other issues, let me know; but as far as I'm concerned, nothing this specific helped me.

So the problem was solved in the build tools:

SDKManager > Android SDK > SDK Tools > Android SDK build-tools 33

Then clicked on *show package details* in the bottom and checked *30.0.3*, entered apply and downloaded it.

[image]

Hope it helps.